# How do I get the middle part of a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get the dates out of this varchar(512) column:

```
CAM; Initial period payment ($3249.58) 01/01/2012 - 01/31/2012; INITIAL Pmt.
```

Looking to return value `01/01/2012` as "Beginning Date" and `01/31/2012` as "Ending Date".

I was reading about stuff and `parsename`, but am pretty new to sql and feel like I'm just getting confused.

Comment: You mention SQL, so are you trying to extract with SQL constructs, or can you do it subsequently in the application layer? If SQL, what database product are you working with?

Comment: Which database are we talking about, and what is the datatype of the column with the text in it?

Comment: [SQL Server BooksOnLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) has got much to offer to a beginner as well as to an advanced user/developer/DBA. [This particular page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx), for instance, lists all string functions supported by the current version of SQL Server, with links to their respective manual pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `SUBSTRING` operations in SQL are always brittle.  Here's something that will work assuming all of your candidate strings are similarly formatted.  I'm sure you improve upon it some with a bit of trial and error:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(1000) = 'CAM; Initial period payment ($3249.58) 01/01/2012 - 01/31/2012; INITIAL Pmt.'

SELECT
    CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(')', @str) + 2, 10)) StartDate,
    CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('-', @str, CHARINDEX(')', @str, 12)) + 2, 10)) EndDate
```

You could replace the use of the `@str` variable with the selection from an actual table.

Comment: Sorry about being vague. I'm working with sql server 2008 R2 and the datatype is varchar(512) and trying to do this in a view.

Comment: Phil, this works great for getting the date. I'll have to see how I can incorporate this into the view so I'll leave this open for a little while longer.

Comment: @PeterUrbina: you might consider doing it as a computed column

Comment: @PeterUrbina, what issue are you having putting this into a View?  It should be as straightforward as adding `FROM <tablename>` and replacing `@str` with your column name.

Comment: I'm just at work now so I'll test it out. The backup I had, for local use, didn't have the right database to test this on. Give you feedback soon.

Comment: I think because I have different lengths of data in this comment field that I will have to figure out how to parse where the date is at. Thanks Phil, this is a great midway point for me.